# Error: Failed to setup browser communication for test case5595c7f4-64d1-494e-b388-be47a3ca9947

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Hello im having error on browser and i don't know how to resolve this. thanks for the future help[image]

Comment: Please attach your html here

Comment: im getting the value from an excel file so that I dont do hardcode on element sin HTML

Comment: are you using apache POI for excel parsing ?

Comment: no i'm not using that

Comment: from where you are getting the xpath or selector of dashboard. Share selector of current dashboard

Comment: hello all my selectors are store in an excel. it will find the element if the string in excel matched the elements on the browser. the problem is that i need a handler wherein i can store the previous row based on the current row selected

Comment: is it a google excel sheet or a local excel sheet of your computer to get xpath? Also share the code where you are accessing excel sheet

Comment: local excel sheet. i editted my post for the code on that @Waqar

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "Domain" and "Dashboard" are table headers (th).

Here is the xpath that you can use

**Simple:** hard coded td index (will break if there is a new cell added before Dashboard cell)

```
"//td[normalize-space(.)='" + dashboard + "']/ancestor::tr/preceding-sibling::tr//td[2]//a"
```

**Return value based on column name:** works irrespective of the position where the dashboard cell is (***preferred***)

```
"//td[normalize-space(.)='" + dashboard + "']/ancestor::tr/preceding-sibling::tr//td[position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='Dashboard']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]//a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int row = 1;
int previousRow=1; // I am assuming that first row index is 1

while(true)
{
    String previousDomain = "";
    String previousDashboard ="";
    if(row != 1){ // check its not the first row else it will throw an exception because row doesn't exist
    previousRow = row - 1;
    previousDomain = sheet.getRow(previousRow ).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();     
    previousDashboard = sheet.getRow(previousRow ).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    }

    String domain = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

   String dashboard = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

   // String report = 
     sheet.getRow(row).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
    if(!domain.equals(null))
    {
        listOfDashboards.add(domain + ";" + dashboard);
        row++;
       // System.out.println("" + domain + "" + dashboard +"" + 
    report);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```